# Multivariate testing for homogeneity

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, multivariate-analysis, heteroscedasticity

I have this dataset with the following variables:

```
GROUP - Categorical (1 2)
DEMOC1 - Categorical (1 2 3 4)
DEMOC2 - Categorical (1 2 3)
DEMOC3 - Categorical (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
DEMON1 - Numeric, continuous (available data from 100 to 160)
DEMON2 - Numeric, continuous (available data from 60 to 120)
DEMON3 - Numeric, continuous (available data from 1.1 to 1.9)
DEMON3 - Numeric, continuous (available data from 45 to 125)
```

I know that I can test if the units are equally spread inside the two GROUPS each time focusing on a different variable. Let's say a t-test (or a similar test) for continuous variables, chi-squared (or a similar test) for categorical variables.

But how can I achieve an overall measure of the homogeneity inside groups with all the variables?

I need a multivariate test like **Hotelling t-test**, but with the possibility to include both categorical and numeric variables.